# Run directory scan as Class

Tags: python, file-system

I've progressed with the directory statistics function and want to proceed by making it a class.

Link to the first version of this code: [Link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240518/run-dir-scan-as-fast-and-efficient-as-possible-clean-code/240551?noredirect=1#comment471897_240551)

**My current state of things:**

**About my namings:**
I first used the name `fcount` as I wanted to have it stand for files and folders as otherwise, the name would be too long. That's why I made the exception to shorten it. I'm still continuing with your more experienced solution for this.
I wrote `pathlib` into the function name because I have the same function above it with `os.walk` as this was my first way to try. But `os.walk` seem to have problems scanning my network drive as it always returned 0 bytes. Therefore I've chosen `pathlib`. Hope that makes sense.

**About my classes:** I'm starting to feel comfortable programming python but as soon as I start to use classes my whole code starts to fall apart and seems to have to be more complex. I know that's just a beginner problem, but as I usually can't solve the issues appearing, I'm careful with that route. I've now rewritten it into a class but facing a few problems now.
I started to try to structure it with the tips from the first CodeReview by writing the file search for-loop into the `__init__` function but python was then saying it can't return a value from `__init__` so I created a new method named `def get_directory_statistics(self, scan_path):`. 
I'm not sure where to input my `scan_path`, into the `__init__`or the first method `def get_directory_statistics(self, scan_path):`.
Your advice to summarize two lines into one, sadly didn't work for me either `return size_and_file_count(size_gb, all_types_count, file_count, folder_count)`. I couldn't get it to work. It's always saying `size_and_file_count` is not defined or other Errors.

Optimizing the code: I outlined above why I sadly can't use os.walk for this. So this won't work for me. And C seems at the moment, not like an option as the only programming language I am familiar with is python and I guess it would be a more complex task to program a wrapper and the code itself in `C`. I think most of it will be I/O bound, yes.

Again I learned a lot from the first answer here on CodeReview!

**Below you'll find my solution after going over all the last notes**

```
class get_size_and_file_count:
    """Gets the total size of a given dir and counts how many folders and files are in the given
        path directory and return a file count, folder count and all non hidden files as a sum"""
    def __init__(self, total_size = 0, non_hidden_files_count = 0, file_count = 0, folder_count = 0):
        self.total_size = total_size
        self.non_hidden_files_count = non_hidden_files_count
        self.file_count = file_count
        self.folder_count = folder_count

    def get_directory_statistics(self, scan_path):
        self.root_directory = Path(scan_path)
        for f in self.root_directory.glob('**/*'):
            if f.is_file():
                self.file_count += 1
                self.total_size += f.stat().st_size
                if not f.name.startswith("."):
                    self.non_hidden_files_count += 1
            if f.is_dir():
                self.folder_count += 1

        directory_statistics = [self.total_size, self.non_hidden_files_count, self.file_count, self.folder_count]
        return directory_statistics

    def print_directory_statistics(self):
        print('Directory path to search:     {}'.format(self.root_directory))
        print('Directory size in GB:         {:.2f}GB'.format(self.total_size / 1.0e9))
        print('Amount of non hidden files:   {}'.format(self.non_hidden_files_count))
        print('Amount of files searched:     {}'.format(self.file_count))
        print('Amount of folders searched:   {}'.format(self.folder_count))


result = get_size_and_file_count()
directory_statistics = result.get_directory_statistics("...") # Store directory statistics in var
result.print_directory_statistics()  # Print directory statistics
```

Comment: It was working and I added the changes that a member suggested, he also suggested to make a new CodeReview out of that. Link to tread 01 at the top of the page.

Comment: Instead of `print_result = ...`, just write `result.print_directory_statistics()`. Indeed, please make sure the code works, then we can review it properly.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback, I've adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

**Style conventions**

Following the PEP style guide, [class names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) should be named with CamelCase and [documentation strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings) should be formatted like the following.

```
class DirectoryStatistics:
    """Gets the total size of a given dir and counts how many folders and
    files are in the given path directory. Also offers a printing utility to output
    the diagnosis results.
    """
    def __init__(self, ...):
        # etc.
```

**Classes**

You can't return values from `__init__` (aka. the class constructor), because it is called when you instantiate an object, thus the return value is the object itself. But you can call methods in your `__init__` method, that's why you should move the content of your `get_directory_statistics` method into the `__init__` method:

```
class DirectoryStatistics:
    """Gets the total size of a given dir and counts how many folders and
    files are in the given path directory. Also offers a printing utility to output
    the diagnosis results.
    """
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.root_directory = path(file_path)
        self.file_count = 0
        self.total_size = 0
        self.non_hidden_files_count = 0
        self.folder_count = 0
        for f in self.root_directory.glob('**/*'):
            if f.is_file():
                self.file_count += 1
                self.total_size += f.stat().st_size
                if not f.name.startswith("."):
                    self.non_hidden_files_count += 1
            if f.is_dir():
                self.folder_count += 1
```

That way, by calling:

```
statistics = DirectoryStatistics(file_path)
```

you run the directory diagnosis and save the results in your object.
Then you can pretty-print the results using your `print_statistics()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the style guide. I've rewritten that part.
Moving the content of `get_directory_statistics()` into `__init__` isn't working for me as I lose the opportunity to return the values. `statistics` in your case wouldn't return anything as it's an object. I would be able to print the values with `print_directory_statistics`, yes but returning the values for further valuation wouldn't be possible.

Comment: The diagnosis results are stored in the `statistics` object, you can retrieve them with `statistics.file_count` for example, that was the reason we restructured the code as a class. Instead of accessing your data via `results[1]` you can now refer to them by name, which is way clearer.

Comment: I see, that worked. What do you think is more pythonic? Writing a method or putting the code in `__init__`?

Comment: Putting the code in `__init__` is definitely the way to go. Otherwise you could instantiate your object and run your `print_directory_results` method without actually running the `get_directory_statistics` method first. This would print only the default values, which is not desirable. An object should never be in an unexpected state, that's why you use the `__init__` method to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

## Unnecessary Flexibility

```
def __init__(self, total_size = 0, non_hidden_files_count = 0, file_count = 0, folder_count = 0):
```

Why do you have the possibility of the caller starting the counters at values other than zero?  Is it really needed?  Or was it just a fancy way of declaring counter variables all in one line?

Note: PEP-8 would require that these keyword parameters not have spaces around the equal signs.

## Stop writing classes

See [Stop writing classes](https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0) on YouTube

Your class should be a function if it is created, one method is called, and results are retrieved.  So let's get rid of your class:

First of all, you want to return results in a nice package, like a named tuple.  We can even add a nice method to this named tuple to print out the results as desired, but it is just decoration.  The results are just plain-old-data:

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import NamedTuple

class DirectoryStats(NamedTuple):
    root_directory: Path
    total_size: int
    files: int
    hidden_files: int
    folders: int

    def print(self):
       print(f'Directory path to search:     {self.root_directory}')
       print(f'Directory size in GB:         {self.total_size / 1.0e9:.2f}GB')
       print(f'Amount of non hidden files:   {self.files-self.hidden_files}')
       print(f'Amount of files searched:     {self.files}')
       print(f'Amount of folders searched:   {self.folders}')
```

Here, I'm using the typing module to automatically create the named tuple from type hints in the declaration.

I'm also using `f'...'` strings to created formatted output without that ugly `"... {} ... ".format(arg)` construct which separates the place where the result is created from the thing that the result is generated from.

Now, the scanning is just a simple function:

```
def get_size_and_file_count(scan_path) -> DirectoryStats:
    """
    Your docstring here.
    """

    files = folders = hidden = total_size = 0
    root = Path(scan_path)
    for f in root.glob('**/*'):
        if f.is_file():
            files += 1
            total_size += f.stat().st_size
            if f.name.startswith("."):
                hidden += 1
        elif f.is_dir():
            folders += 1

    return DirectoryStats(root, total_size, files, hidden, folders)
```

Pretty straight forward.  The function initializes some counters, walks the `scan_path`, counts stuff, and then in the return statement, constructs the named tuple we defined above.

I've removed a double negative.  Instead of the file name does not start with a period incrementing a not hidden count, I count the hidden files.

Example usage:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = directory_statistics('.')
    result.print()
```

Produces on my machine, in my directory:

```
Directory path to search:     .
Directory size in GB:         0.00GB
Amount of non hidden files:   22
Amount of files searched:     23
Amount of folders searched:   4
```